# How reduce padding to the left of actionbar app logo in Android

Tags: android

I know I can add padding by creating a custom drawable with built in padding, but how do I reduce this padding ( indicated below)?

The empty space is there because this is the home page and the back button is hidden. I'm thinking maybe there's a way to tell the UI to not put in space for the back button.

[image]

Comment: Are you using the ToolBar or the ActionBar? What version of app compat?

Answer (score 1):

Use toolbar. You can add the icon to the xml easily.

Check this post of google developers blog: http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

you have to add the some actionbar method to avoid this

```
actionbar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionbar.setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(
                android.R.color.transparent)));
        actionbar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        View customView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.actionbar_main, null);
        actionbar.setCustomView(customView);
        Toolbar parent = (Toolbar) customView.getParent();
        parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Toolbar parent = (Toolbar) customView.getParent();
parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0,0);
```

Comment: Hi Krishna - your answer is very terse; it would be better if you could add some explanation and context about how and why this solution would work?

Answer (score -1):

in your manifest, you can specify an alternate image for the action bar "home" button.

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:logo="@drawable/logo"
    ...
```

by default it uses `icon`.